# How to define create method for intermediate class during in mapping in Dozer

Tags: mapping, dozer

Here's my scenario, I have 2 classes "com.project.ClassA" and "com.project.ClassB", I'm trying to map the fields ClassA.name to ClassB.person.nameObj.firstName.

As you can see, Dozer needs to create person object and nameObj before it can do the mapping, there is some factory classes to initiate the Person and NameObj objects.

I know we can define custom create method in field and class level, but that only applies to the field or the class that you are mapping. In my example, the mapping are between 2 String fields, but 2 objects are required to be created before the mapping is performed.

The error I'm getting now is 
org.dozer.MappingException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.project.ClassB.Person.()

Any helps or ideas will greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Two things
1. ClassB needs a constructor which initialized obj Person, similarly Person needs a constructor to initialize nameobj.
2. accessor and mutator methods should be present (getters and setters).

After you do both these steps this should work.